# Deploy Logs - Error: No application module specified - Digital Ocean - FastAPI

Tags: python, deployment, fastapi, digital-ocean

I am trying to delpoy FastAPI app on digital ocean. My folder structure for fastAPI is:

```
app.py
gunicorn.config.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
```

here's whats inside gunicorn.config.py

```
bind = "0.0.0.0:8080"
workers = 2
worker_class = "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker"
```

Procfile

```
gunicorn --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --config gunicorn.config.py app:app
```

requirements.txt

```
fastapi
selenium
uvicorn
gunicorn
```

The building phase is successfull but i get `Error: No application module specified.` in deploy logs.